# Not able to inject a custom value during dynamic component creation

Tags: angular

I have to inject custom values based on each component instantiation.I don't want to set it to a property after creation, but would want to do a constructor injection.

This is what I tried

```
  let customData = {
  p: 1,
  q: 'damean'
};

let injector = Injector.create([{
  provide: CustomData,
  useValue: customData,
  deps: [],
},
]);

console.log('injector at parent level', injector);
let componentRef = this.containerRef.createComponent(factory, 0, injector);
```

But, I get an error which says no providers injected, when I look for it here

Err: NullInjectorError: No provider for customData!

```
public constructor(private injector: Injector) {
  console.log('injector', injector);
  console.log(this.injector.get("customData"));
}
```

I have created a stackblitz for testing. Any help is appreciated.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7wqiiy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is a type, Look at this [example](https://angular.io/api/core/Injector#example)

Import

```
import { CustomData } from './custom-data'; //into home component
```

And provide a type to get from injector

```
 console.log('injector', injector);
 console.log(this.injector.get(CustomData));
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mzkr1b)

Answer (score 1):

Use the resolveAndCreate() method, which resolves an array of providers and creates an injector from those providers. The config parameter is the same as @ngModule.providers

```
const injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
      {
        provide: 'customData',
        useValue: customData
      }
    ]);
```

Then Use Inject decorator to inject

```
 constructor(@Inject('customData') private customData) {
    console.log(this.customData);   
  }
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d62tcp